# Bash alias doesn't work, identical command does

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I have created a bash command to pass each .mp3 file in a folder to a commandline media player, omxplayer. It also sets the player's volume and throws away the feedback from the player:

```
for i in *.mp3; do omxplayer --vol -2000 "$i" > /dev/null; done
```

The `--vol -2000` sets the volume.

This command works well, so I decided to create an alias for it called omxall:

```
alias omxall="for i in *.mp3; do omxplayer --vol -2000 > /dev/null "$i"; done"
```

The actual command is identical, but it does not work the same. The first one correctly plays all .mp3 files and the second hangs around for a few seconds then finishes.

**Please note:** I am putting my aliases into `~/.bash_aliases`. I have other working aliases in the same file, so their location is not a problem.

---

Now I realise that the `/dev/null/` will hamper troubleshooting by suppressing all other helpful information, so I have tried without it:

```
for i in *.mp3; do omxplayer --vol -2000 "$i"; done
```

This does the right job.

```
alias omxall="for i in *.mp3; do omxplayer --vol -2000 "$i"; done"
```

This brings up the player's usage page.

What is happening here? Am I wrong in assuming that an alias should behave in exactly the same way as a command typed in at the command prompt?

---

#### It was caused by a silly error on my part, but I am leaving this question here because someone else may do the same thing.

Comment: You did mess up with quoting. You should use single quotes for the outer quoting, so the shell does not expand `$i` when the alias is defined. You can see the difference when calling `alias` without any parameter.

Comment: @ridgy: Oh, I did not think of that!  Thanks so much! I'm going to test it now...

Comment: @ridgy: Yes, it was my quoting. Thanks so much. BTW I am new to bash and aliases, but I know from other coding what issues using the wrong quotes can cause.

Comment: @ridgy That makes for an answer, do you mind adding it?

Comment: @dessert, just what I was about to ask, thanks.

Comment: For complex commands I suggest you use functions and not aliases